# Getting past the guys in Hotal Richissime

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do you get past the two guys in Hotel Richissime, firstly the chef who is a dishwasher and says he is watching you like a watchdog, and secondly, the guy who blocked the door with his broom?

Comment: Consult the all-knowing helix fossil.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't - they're just blocked doors, similar to the rooms in the [Sinnoh Pokemon Mansion](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Mansion_%28Sinnoh%29).